# Difference between .where() and .doc() related to number of reads

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

If I get a document by `.collection('users').where('uid', isEqualTo, widget.uid)` or by `.collection('users').doc(widget.uid)` will I read the database the same number of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are charged one read for every document that matches your query when it is executed.  It does not matter how you make that query - what matters is the number of documents returned to the app.

If your `where` query returns exactly one document, then it is not any different in price or performance than one using `doc`.

Answer (score 0):

The former returns a [QueryFieldFilterConstraint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.queryfieldfilterconstraint.md#queryfieldfilterconstraint_class) while the latter returns a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.md#documentreference_class). The DocumentReference is preferable because it can be used to write, read, or listen to the location.

Naturally, a query must *read* every id in the referenced collection (this is probably indexed) while a reference points to a single id. In terms of pricing, [aggregateQueries documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/aggregation-queries) is actually returning a page not found error at the moment?

See [Understand Cloud Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#aggregation_queries)

> For aggregation queries such as count(), you are charged one document
> read for each batch of up to 1000 index entries matched by the query.
> For aggregation queries that match 0 index entries, there is a minimum
> charge of one document read.
>
> For example, count() operations that match between 0 and 1000 index
> entries are billed for one document read. For a count() operation that
> matches 1500 index entries, you are billed 2 document reads.